# uitableview question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

I have 2 `UITableView` in `UIView`, when reload the data of the second `UITableView`.

I set for example the number of rows to 345.

The `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called only 10 times when calling the `reloadData` function

NB: the displayed number of rows is 10 in design time .

How can we overcome such problem?

```
    if(  tableView == self.SearchResult) 

    {


        if (QueryClass  ) 
        {


            NSLog(@"%d",[QueryClass->StudyResults count]); // 500 row 
        return [QueryClass->StudyResults count];


        }

        else {
            return 0 ; 
        }


        //return [SearchResult_study count ] ; 

        //return 0  ; 



    }


}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"BEFORE ENTERING %d",indexPath.row);
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil) {


        if(tableView == self.Settings )

        {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        if (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 0 ){



            UILabel *PatientLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 120, 25)];
            PatientLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            PatientLabel.tag = 1;
            PatientLabel.text = @"Selected Node " ; 
            [cell.contentView addSubview:PatientLabel];






            SelectedNode = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 10, 400, 30)];
            SelectedNode.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            SelectedNode.tag = 24 ; 
            SelectedNode.text = @" Select Node " ;


            [cell.contentView addSubview:SelectedNode];

            cell.accessoryType =  UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator ; 








        }
        if (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 1 ) {


            //cell.textLabel.text = "Patient Name";



            UILabel *PatientLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 120, 25)];
            PatientLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            PatientLabel.tag = 1;
            PatientLabel.text = @"Study Date" ; 
            [cell.contentView addSubview:PatientLabel];





            StudyDate = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 10, 400, 30)];
            StudyDate.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            StudyDate.tag = 1;
            StudyDate.text = @"Select Date" ; 
            [cell.contentView addSubview:StudyDate];

            cell.accessoryType =  UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator ; 



        }
        if (indexPath.row == 1 && indexPath.section == 1 ) {


            //cell.textLabel.text = "Patient Name";



            UILabel *PatientLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 120, 25)];
            PatientLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            PatientLabel.tag = 1;
            PatientLabel.text = @"Patient Name" ; 
            [cell.contentView addSubview:PatientLabel];






            PtienttextField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 10, 400, 30)];


            PtienttextField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
            PtienttextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
            PtienttextField.delegate = self;
            PtienttextField.tag = 21 ; 
            [PtienttextField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleBezel];
            [PtienttextField resignFirstResponder];

            [cell.contentView addSubview:PtienttextField];




        }
        if (indexPath.row == 2 && indexPath.section == 1 ) {


            //cell.textLabel.text = "Patient Name";



            UILabel *PatientLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 120, 25)];
            PatientLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            PatientLabel.tag = 1;
            PatientLabel.text = @"Acc No" ; 
            [cell.contentView addSubview:PatientLabel];






            ACCNOtextField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 10, 400, 30)];


            ACCNOtextField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
            ACCNOtextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
            ACCNOtextField.delegate = self;
            ACCNOtextField.tag = 22 ; 
            [ACCNOtextField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleBezel];
            [ACCNOtextField resignFirstResponder];

            [cell.contentView addSubview:ACCNOtextField];




        }
        if (indexPath.row == 3 && indexPath.section == 1 ) {


            //cell.textLabel.text = "Patient Name";



            UILabel *PatientLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 120, 25)];
            PatientLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            PatientLabel.tag = 1;
            PatientLabel.text = @"Modality " ; 
            [cell.contentView addSubview:PatientLabel];






            ModalityLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 10, 400, 30)];
            ModalityLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            ModalityLabel.tag = 23 ; 
            ModalityLabel.text = @" Select Modality " ;


            [cell.contentView addSubview:ModalityLabel];

            cell.accessoryType =  UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator ; 




        }
        if (indexPath.row == 4 && indexPath.section == 1 ) {


            //cell.textLabel.text = "Patient Name";



            UILabel *PatientLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 120, 25)];
            PatientLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            PatientLabel.tag = 1;
            PatientLabel.text = @"Birth Date " ; 
            [cell.contentView addSubview:PatientLabel];






            DateOfBirth = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 10, 400, 30)];
            DateOfBirth.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            DateOfBirth.tag = 24 ; 
            DateOfBirth.text = @" Select Date " ;


            [cell.contentView addSubview:DateOfBirth];

            cell.accessoryType =  UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator ; 




        }
        if (indexPath.row == 5 && indexPath.section == 1 ) {

            UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(Search:)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
            [button setTitle:@"Search" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            button.frame = CGRectMake(140, 10, 400, 30);

            [cell.contentView addSubview: button ] ; 

        }

        }
        if(  tableView == self.SearchResult)

        {
            NSLog(@"ENTERED SEARCH RESULT %d",indexPath.row) ;


            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];


            FindResultsClass *data = [[FindResultsClass alloc] init];


             // repeat just the first 10 values

            data = [QueryClass->StudyResults objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
            cell.textLabel.text = data.patientName;
            /*if (data.StudyDate) 
            {
                NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/YYYY"];
                NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:data.StudyDate];
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
                [dateFormat release];
            }*/

        }


  }

    // Configure the cell.

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly? If it's the fact that cellForRowAtIndexPath only gets called 10 times, that shouldn't be a problem. It only gets called when cells need to be created to be displayed, so if only 10 are visible initially then that is not a problem in itself.

Comment: @André  the problem when scroll the tableview I noticed that data be repeated ,not the 345 value , only the first ten be repeated

Comment: if the same cells are repeated you have an issue in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: which error may be occured in cellForRowAtIndexPath, I updated the question with the function

Comment: Please, be clear with your question. Provide some code as example and let us understand your problem. What are you doing? What are you expecting? What are you getting instead?

Comment: Seriously: I won't fly over such a poorly formatted code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the separation of intitalization and return of cells in both tables solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` will only get called as needed, which is when the row comes into view on screen.  If you need to iterate over all 345 rows for some reason, you'll have to do that manually in another method.

Comment: why use another method , while I test the same code just for one table and it worked very well, while only few rows appeaered

Comment: @AMH, perhaps I don't understand your question then.  Can you state it another way?